# TypeError: Cannot read property 'project' of undefined (with elements in my array ...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem on my react app with FireStore database.

Here is my state with a `console.log` :

[Picture of the state project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9p3D.png)

I have my documents.project array not empty but I have this error on my app :

[image: Picture of the react error]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow TheFugu! Please try to include the code you have written, the state structure, and the error in the question instead of just linking to external resources.

Comment: Please share the error in text. They are more portable.

Comment: post your code, not pictures of code, please

Comment: I think this an another "Ajax" related issue.. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/1823841

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `documents` variable is a array so you either need to loop through the array to get the index value and use it to access all the objects with `project` property like:

```
for(var i=0; i<documents.length; i++){
  console.log(documents[i].project);
}
```

Or you need to explicitly define the index value as `documents[0].project` to get the `project` value of object at index `0` and so on.

Comment: documents is not an array. project is but documents is an object

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :-)

Comment: @TheFugu glad to help